# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from primefaces getRowData in dynamic columns

Tags: arrays, dynamic, primefaces, datatable

I'm new here and have looked for quite some time for similar problems without success.
If this problem has been solved elsewhere, please point me to the answer or please show me where I can read the appropriate documentation. Thanks.

**The situation:**
I have a DataTable with dynamic columns. 
Filtering and sorting work.

I need to implement a context menu that reads a selcted row in the table and takes different actions depending on the value in a cell of the selected row.
When I try to get the row a 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
is thrown.

Help and tips would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Arthur

**The DataTable with columns and context menu:**

```
<p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
    <p:menuitem value="Projektnavi" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                actionListener="#{dataView.onContextMenuSelect('PROJEKTNAVI')}"/>

    <p:menuitem value="Edit NOTIZ" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                actionListener="#{dataView.onContextMenuSelect('NOTIZ')}"/>

    <p:menuitem value="Edit STATUS" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                actionListener="#{dataView.onContextMenuSelect('STATUS')}"/>

    <p:menuitem value="Edit COVER" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                actionListener="#{dataView.onContextMenuSelect('COVER')}"/>

    <p:menuitem value="Edit PFAD" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                actionListener="#{dataView.onContextMenuSelect('PFAD')}"/>
</p:contextMenu>

<p:dataTable draggableColumns="true"
             draggableRows="true"
             filteredValue="#{dataView.filtered}"
             id="dataTable" 
             lazy="true"
             paginator="true"
             paginatorPosition="bottom"
             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             resizableColumns="true"
             resizeMode="expand"
             rowIndexVar="rowIndexVar"                                
             rows="1000"
             rowKey="#{layout[column.property]}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollHeight="100%"
             selection="#{dataView.selected}"
             selectionMode="single"
             sortMode="multiple"
             style="margin-bottom:0"
             value="#{dataView.lazyModel}"
             var="layout" 
             widgetVar="widgetDataTable">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{dataView.onRowSelect}" />

    <p:columns columnIndexVar="colIndex" 
               filterBy="#{layout[column.property]}"
               filterMatchMode="in"
               filterStyle="display: none; visibility: hidden;"
               sortBy="#{layout[column.property]}" 
               style="text-align: #{column.align};"
               value="#{dataView.columns}" 
               width="#{column.width}"
               var="column">
        <f:param name="rowId" value="#{rowIndexVar}" />
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{column.header}
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:inputText id="filter" onkeyup="PF('widgetDataTable').filter()" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndexVar} - #{layout[column.property]}" />
    </p:columns>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:dialog header="Info" widgetVar="layoutDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
            <p:outputPanel id="layoutDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="true">
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

**The column model code**

```
static public class ColumnModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2504875837397753172L;

    private final String header;
    private final String property;
    private final String align;
    private final Integer width;

    public ColumnModel(String header, String property, String align, Integer width) {
        this.header = header;
        this.property = property;
        this.align = align;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public Integer getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public String getAlign() {
        return align;
    }
}
```

**The Column generation code:**

```
protected void setDynamicColumns() {

    String[] columnKeys = dataController.getTableHeaders();
    columns = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String columnKey : columnKeys) {
        HashMap<String, Object> columnInfo
                = dataController.getColumnInfo(layoutName, columnKey);

        // Get field names and values from ab_umsatz_layout
        Integer width = (Integer) columnInfo.get("FELD_WIDTH");
        String align = (String) columnInfo.get("FELD_ALIGN");

        ColumnModel columnModel
                = new ColumnModel(columnKey.trim().toUpperCase(),
                        columnKey.trim(), align, width);
        columns.add(columnModel);
    }
}
```

**The onRowSelect method:**

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) selectEvent.getComponent();
    try {
        Object selectedRow = dataTable.getRowData();

        System.out.println(selectedRow);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The generated exception:**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
    at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.getRowData(LazyDataModel.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowData(UIData.java:371)
    at de.kma.kmaprojektliste.view.DataView.onRowSelect(DataView.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processCustomArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:107)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:82)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.event.AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AbstractAjaxBehaviorEvent.java:38)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:805)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem or do you have any leads? I'm currently batteling the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

Try to override getRowData() method in LazyDataModel. you will probably override a few more methods because they are working with global variable of this class and it is the trouble.
try this.

```html
@Override
    public TEntity getRowData() {
        int tempIndex= rowIndex;
        if (tempIndex >= 0 && tempIndex < data.size())
            return data.get(tempIndex);
        else return null;
    }
```

It solved the problem for me. I am not sure if the condition is necessary, but I think problem was that rowIndex was rewritten during this method and it was possible that it was set to -1.

For me, this situation occured only when I used p:datatable with lazy loading and over that I had a p:dialog with buttons. Usually user had to submit the form in dialog very very quickly.